# Disable Mobile View on Wordpress 4.3.1?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Does anybody know how to turn off mobile viewing in wordpress 4.3.1? I am done customizing the template (Bridge template) and this is the last thing I have been trying to fix, as it really doesn't look good in mobile mode.

I have looked everywhere online and can't find a good answer, so any help is much appreciated.

For reference, it is the wordpress version that looks like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile responsiveness of front-end design is part of the theme or template you are using and it is not function of main WordPress software itself. You will need to remove media queries code in your currently active theme to disable mobile responsiveness from your front-end of the website.

**Note:** By the way it is recommended to have your WordPress website to be fully responsive as many users will access your website using small devices like Mobile or Tablet.

However if you must remove mobile responsiness as per your situation. Open style.css or any other stylsheet you may find in your currently active theme and comment the code related to Media queries any code which starts with something like following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px) {

 }
```

You may comment such code block with following code so that you could revert if something goes wrong i.e.

```
/** 
   @media only screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
   }
     **/
```